# LLVM Error when compiling a model for IPU

Tags: ipu

I’ve been playing about with some of the [Graphcore examples](https://github.com/graphcore/examples), specifically the [TensorFlow CNN examples](https://github.com/graphcore/examples/tree/master/applications/tensorflow/cnns/training). I’ve been training ResNet with various command line options quite a few times successfully and now whatever command line I use I get the following error:

```
LLVM ERROR: IO failure on output stream: No space left on device
```

Why has the IPU run out of memory? Did a previous program exit unsuccessfully and leave the IPUs in a polluted state? A reboot helps for a while and then I run into the error again.

Answer (score 2):

“Device” in this context actually refers to the host storage device rather than to the IPU device. This error is telling you that the disk being used for compilation is full.  You can have a look at disk usage on an Ubuntu based host with the `du` or `df` commands. If any of the disks/filesystems are at or close to 100% full then you should delete some files to make space for compilation. The reason you are seeing reboots helping for a while is likely because the `/tmp` directory is being cleared; it will then fill up over time as you use the system. To mitigate against this it is advisable to have a large scratch file system on the machine you’re using to compile programs for the IPU.